# script not working with internet explorer - simple dom scrape with querySelectorAll and push into array

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm not very experienced with Javascript so when I managed to create this script I was feeling pretty good. But, alas, it seems to fail with Internet Explorer and I don't know why.

Can anyone spot what IE would not like about this script?

From looking inside of our Google Analytics this script has failed with IE 9 and 11.

```
function() {

// build products object
var prods = [];
var count = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomLocation').length;

for(i=0; i < count; i++) {

    //set granular vars
    prd = {};
    var brand = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomLocation')[i].textContent;
    var name = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomDescription')[i].textContent;
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomSplashPriceAmount')[i].textContent;
    var quantity = window.session_context_vars.BookingContext.Booking.ReservationLineItems[i].ReservationCharges.length/2;

    //add to prd object
    prd.brand = brand;
    prd.name = name;
    prd.price = price;
    prd.quantity = quantity;

   //add to prods array
   prods.push(prd);
}

   var ecommerceData = {
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
       'actionField': {'id': {{transaction id}},
                       'revenue': {{transaction amount}},
                       'tax': {{tax}}},

       'products': prods
      }
    }
   };
   return ecommerceData;
}
```

Comment: which version of IE would this be?

Comment: Hi @MarcB so far Google Analytics shows that only IE 9 and 11 have seen this script. In all instances it failed.

Comment: Do you have any insight on where exactly it failed?

Comment: Save your selectors in var before.

Comment: @romuleald in what way? I don't understand?

Comment: First it will be much faster, and not sure, but you cannot use [i] on the directly on the querySelector

Comment: I'm using querySelectorAll() which returns an array, distinct from querySelector(). Since it returns an array I used [i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what @romuleald was saying, this is probably a little bit better way to structure your code.  It eliminates the need to find the same arrays each time you go through your *for* loop.

```
function() {
// build products object
var prods = [];
var brand = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomLocation');
var name = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomDescription');
var price = document.querySelectorAll('.txtStayRoomSplashPriceAmount');

for(i=0; i < brand.length; i++) {

//set granular vars
var prd = {};

//add to prd object
prd.brand = brand[i].textContent;
prd.name = name[i].textContent;
prd.price = price[i].textContent;
prd.quantity = window.session_context_vars.BookingContext.Booking.ReservationLineItems[i].ReservationCharges.length/2;;

//add to prods array
prods.push(prd);
}

var ecommerceData = {
'ecommerce': {
  'purchase': {
   'actionField': {'id': {{transaction id}},
                   'revenue': {{transaction amount}},
                   'tax': {{tax}}},

   'products': prods
  }
}
};
return ecommerceData;
}
```

As for the error, can you give us more details?  What error is thrown in the debugger?

Comment: Ah I see now, efficiency for the loop. Thanks. It's hard to determine where the ie error is, I only know because our analytics reporting tool shows missing data for brand, name and price only for people on ie browser. Maybe this update will fix it, I'll monitor our tracking and let you know how I get on.